# Video format issue in android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using android studio version **2.3.3**
and try to insert a video in to project. But it is copied as text file and shows like this..[VideoFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJfPd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can create asset folder inside your project and store your video
>   in that folder.

And, you can get it by using following code

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

Comment: Sorry bro it show me the error "Cannot resolve the symbol raw"? -How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

android studio supports dozens of formats, its just depends upon your target version of android device just check [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html).

Comment: android studio show this kind of files as a text while you read the file dynamically it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Some File Format That android studio does not open directly Support.. Like **.sqlite,.mp4,.mp3**.

If you want To show that file then do some steps below:

right click your project choose option **Show in explorer** and You Can Play And Modified this file outside android studio with appropriate software.

Comment: but it iis not playing in the app @JJG

Comment: send your some Code snippets.. Do you add any Video Player code to play this video??

Answer (score 0):

[Errors are fixed Successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3i5o.png)Thankyou all for your kind responses.Now i have cleared all the errors.Video is playing in my app.Thank you again.